# WPF DataGrid, converting value in cell

Tags: c#

I have DataGrid with column populated by value of field xxx:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=xxx, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Width="140" Header="Some Header"/>
```

I am now allowed to make any changes to class being used to populate this DataGrid. I created MyConverter but I do not know how I should modify my xaml to get it working. Any help on this please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an instance of your converter in XAML and apply it using `StaticResource`-

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
       <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    .....

    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=xxx, Mode=OneWay,
                                  Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
                    Width="140" Header="Some Header"/>
<DataGrid>
```

where `local` is namespace where your converter resides and declare at top of your XAML -

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
```

Also you should read on how to implement [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) on your bindings. This link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx) will be helpful to get you started.